# I get undefined when I search using GitHub API with angularjs

Tags: angularjs

here is the code

the view code:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="model.org" />
<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Load Repos" ng-click="getRepos(model.org)" ng-hide="model.repos" />
<div class="col-md-6">
   <table class="table table-striped" ng-show="model.repos">
      <tr>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Language</th>
         <th></th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="r in model.repos">
         <td>
            <h4>{{r.name}}</h4> {{r.description}}
         </td>
         <td>{{r.language}}</td>
         <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="loadDetail(r.name)" value="Detail"> </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

and this is the inside the controller:

```
$scope.model = {
   number: 0,
   result: 'Ready'
};

$scope.getRepos = getRepos;

function getRepos(org) {
   $http.get('https://api.github.com/orgs/org/repos').then(function(response) {
      $scope.model.repos = response.data;
   }, function(response) {
      alert(response.error);
      $scope.model.repos = 'Error: ' + response.data.message;
   })
}
```

when I click the button that has the ng-click="getRepos(javascript); I get undefined but if I copied this link https://api.github.com/orgs/javascript/repos to a browser it returns data!

what am I missing here?

Comment: what is `javascript` in the argument of `getRepos(javascript)` inside the html? it would have to be a scope variable, else you will get undefined.

Comment: your URL https://api.github.com/orgs/org/repos returns no data

Comment: @CozyAzure I updated the code to make it clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you wanted to pass the parameter to `getRepos` in your GET url, like:

```
function getRepos(org) {
   $http.get('https://api.github.com/orgs/' + org + '/repos').then(function(response) {
      $scope.model.repos = response.data;
   }, function(response) {
      alert(response.error);
      $scope.model.repos = 'Error: ' + response.data.message;
   })
}
```

Comment: Omg! how I missed this lol, I am really a very starter at this. Thanks @Dario